# Getting foreign tables value laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

here is an example

Table Structure

```
Game
--id
--game


Posts
--id
--game_id
--post_text





 class Posts extends Eloquent {
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 protected $table = 'posts';
      public function games() {
    return $this->hasOne('games','id');
}
}

 class Games extends Eloquent {
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 protected $table = 'games';
   public function posts() {
            return $this->belongsTo('posts','game_id');
   }
}
```

I need to get the game name of a certain post. How can I get it using eloquent?

here is my initial code

```
echo $post->games['game'];
```

but I get the wrong data.

The way it queries is this.

```
   'query' => string 'select * from `games` where `games`.`id` = ? limit 1' (length=52)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 5
```

Comment: you can  do like this $game = Posts::find(1)->games;  echo $game->game; one more thing use Modal name as plural like Post , Game instead Posts, Games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly Eloquent model names are not plural, so by default they should be Game and Post.
Secondly relationship return values must be changed. In hasOne and belongsTo you will need to use model class names like below. I also left out some optional code which is not required for the code to work.

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
  public function game() {
    return $this->hasOne('Game');
  }
}

class Game extends Eloquent {
  public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
  }
}
```

Now you can get the game name by `$post->game->name`